# What would happed if I activated an unactivated windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I was wondering if activating an unactivated windows would reset or delete things I had on unactivated windows?

Comment: @McDonald's What are you talking about? ----- @ AlexD. the answer is no, it won't reset nor get rid of anything if you were to activate Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activating your windows will not in anyway affect, reset or delete any of your things you had on an unactivated windows, instead, you will be granted extra privileges after activating your windows.

So feel very safe to activate your windows as it's the best thing to do, because not activating your windows itself leaves you with this annoying message that is always there at the bottom-right of your screen **Your windows is not activated**, aside that, you won't have access to any windows update, which that alone leaves you very **VULNERABLE** to any attack.

All that being said, again I say. **`Activating your windows will not in anyway affect, reset or delete any of your things you had on an unactivated windows`**

Comment: But Windows update can be installed manually with KB packages.